# JSON schema conditionally required fields for at least 1 element of array for nested property

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema, ajv

I have an object:

```
{
  "name": "one",
  "lines": [{
    "id": "1"
  }]
}
```

I want to create a JSON schema that will validate the next scenario: if name is "one", then lines array with a single required property "id" is correct, if name is "two", then lines array should have at least 1 element with non empty field "foo" with nested field "type" that has either value "abc" or "xyz":

```
{
  "name": "two",
  "lines": [{
    "id": "1",
    "foo": {
      "type": "abc"
    }
  },
    {
      "id": "2"
    }]
}
```

I created a schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["one", "two"]
    },
    "lines": {
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/ItemLine"
      },
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "ItemLine": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Foo"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": ["id"]
    },
    "Foo": {
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/FooType"
        }
      },
      "type": "object"
    },
    "FooType": {
      "enum": [
        "abc",
        "xyz"
      ],
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to add condition explained above, something like:
if (name == "two") then iterate through all lines and check that at least 1 itemLine must have required property foo with types either "abc" or "xyz".
I'm using ajv library to validate json object. I don't want to split validation into JSON schema defined in file and custom logic in code. Is it possible to define this if-else and loop in JSON schema?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if-then-else` to accomplish this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "description": "JSON schema generated with JSONBuddy https://www.json-buddy.com",
  "type": "object",
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "name": { "const": "two" }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "lines": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/ItemLineBase" },
        "contains": { "$ref": "#/definitions/ItemLineEx" }
      }
    }    
  },
  "else": {
    "properties": {
      "lines": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/ItemLineBase" }
      }
    }   
  },
  "definitions": {
    "ItemLineBase": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "foo": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Foo" },
        "id": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": [ "id" ]
    },
    "ItemLineEx": {
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/ItemLineBase" },
        { "required": [ "id", "foo" ] }
      ]
    },
    "Foo": {
      "properties": {
        "type": { "enum": [ "abc", "xyz" ] }
      },
      "type": "object"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! Yes, it solves 1st part of the problem. The 2nd part is to make "foo" required not for all ItemLineEx but at least for 1, that means when we get ItemLineEx array, then at least 1 item in this array should have "foo" property.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the schema's `contains` part. I updated the answer providing a better solution.